# IE breaks my site design

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

My wordpress theme looks correct in chrome , Firefox and Opera (latest versions as of dec 2012)

when I look at it in IE 9 , even with compatibility view on, it doesnt look right.

The blue bar with the menu in it looks too thick

Here is the link. 
http://www.kyaniworld.biz/products/sunrise/

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple! You can find a solution by creating a `css` targeting only IE. So here is a helpful [link](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/). You don't have to worry about the added download data for the user. The `css` file targeting IE will only download when the site is opened form IE browser. Hope I helped!

PS: A headsUp: You should verify your site in all IE versions (i go down to IE 7). Every version has it's own bugs and problems.

[edit] Just came across this. The answer to all my problems: The 'css' reset :

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
width: auto;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
background: transparent;
}
```